# How does one use the tags option when creating resources with the aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cli

Trying to create a tagged item with aws cli.

```
aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $group_name --description $my_description
```

I can't parse the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-security-group.html)

```
--tag-specifications (list)
```

I tried with

```
--tag-specifications KEY=Name,Value=$something

and --tags Key=Name,Value=$something
and --tags [Key=Name,Value=$something]
and --tags {[Key=Name,Value=$something]}
```

Answer (score 9):

We need to pass two properties

- ResourceType: in this case `security-group`
- Tags: array of key-value object

  ```
  aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name 'test' --description 'test desc' --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=security-group,Tags=[{Key=purpose,Value=production},{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}]'
  ```